# Date Validation android java

Tags: java, android, date

I have two date time picker in my projects, which is start date and end date, 
but the problem is let say, if i choose 18/10/2014 for start date, the end date is 1/11/2014, the end date is invalid as the day 1 for is invalid as it is smaller than day 18. Need help for this

```
//start date
    TableRow r8 = new TableRow(this);
    TextView tvStartDate = new TextView(this);
    tvStartDate.setText("Start Date: ");
    final EditText etStartDate = new EditText(this);
    etStartDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar dateNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = dateNow.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = dateNow.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = dateNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dp;
            dp = new DatePickerDialog(AddPetActivity.this, new OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    selectedmonth = selectedmonth + 1;
                    etStartDate.setText("" + selectedday + "/" + selectedmonth + "/" + selectedyear);
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            dp.setTitle("Select Date");
            dp.show();
        }
    });
    r8.addView(tvStartDate);
    r8.addView(etStartDate);
    tb.addView(r8);

    //end date
    TableRow r9 = new TableRow(this);
    TextView tvEndDate = new TextView(this);
    tvEndDate.setText("End Date: ");
    final EditText etEndDate = new EditText(this);
    etEndDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar dateNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = dateNow.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = dateNow.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = dateNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dp;
            dp = new DatePickerDialog(AddPetActivity.this, new OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    selectedmonth = selectedmonth + 1;

                    etEndDate.setText("" + selectedday + "/" + selectedmonth + "/" + selectedyear);
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            dp.setTitle("Select Date");
            dp.show();
        }
    });
    r9.addView(tvEndDate);
    r9.addView(etEndDate);
    tb.addView(r9);

=========================================================================================
```

For the validation part startdate and end date

```
else if (CheckDate(today, etStartDate.getText().toString()) == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Start Date!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            else{
                if (!etEndDate.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                    if (CheckDate( etStartDate.getText().toString(), etEndDate.getText().toString()) == false)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid End Date!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


=========================================================================================
```

last part

```
private boolean CheckDate(String fromDate, String toDate)
{   
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
        Date dateFrom = null;
        Date dateTo = null;
        try {
            dateFrom = sdf.parse(fromDate);
            dateTo = sdf.parse(toDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    if (dateTo.after(dateFrom) == true) 
        return true; 
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Comment: i don't understand you constraint. 1/11 is after 18/10

Comment: yes, the start date is 18/10 then end date is 1/11, the end date keep shows invalid date as 1 is smaller than 18, i have to put 19 in order to make it valid.

Comment: that's because `mm` is for minutes, you need `MM` for month.